# Using a php function inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to run a php function from a javascript code, to be more specific I got a button that delete a record from the database. The function that does that named

```
delete_post($id)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" 
onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {<?php delete_post($row['id']);?>}">
```

When I click the button, there is no alert box. The funny thing is if I don't call a function inside the php code and I do something else such as echo the alert does pop out but the php code doesn't executed.

So, how can I do that? How can I run a php code inside my javascript onClick code.

Comment: PHP runs of the server, JS on the client. Your JS would need to talk to the server using AJAX for it to delete a record (unless you post a form that then loads the page again). Please consider security - row id alone is not secure.

Comment: the best way to go to avoid security flaws would be JS/ajax...split your code and have a seperate JS and PHP file...if you need help doing this, let me know...will whoop you up ans answer

Comment: @VyrenMedia I do need help, never used ajax before.

Comment: @ImriPersiado I added and answer check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. PHP is supposed to be run before the page loads, thus giving it the name Pre-Hypertext Protocol. If you want to run PHP after a page loads via JavaScript, the best approach would be linking to a new page that runs the PHP, then returning the user back.

**file1.php:**

```
...
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onClick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) document.location.href='file2.php';">
...
```

**file2.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
delete_post($row['id']);
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=file1.php" />
</head>
<body>
<p>You will be redirected soon; please wait. If you are not automatically redirected, <a href="file1.php">click here</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming you would have multiple IDs, you can keep them all onto one redirect page:

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?')) document.location='file2.php?id=2'; // file1.php
delete_post($row[$_GET["id"]]); // file2.php
```

But do not put PHP code directly into the query string, or your site could be susceptible to [PHP injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Comment: Good answer, but I have to point out that PHP now stands for "PHP: Hypertext Processor" (and used to stand for "Personal Home Page" from the name PHP Tools).

Comment: btw there is a big secure flaw in that way.. everyone will be able to load exmaple.com/fil2.php?id=x and they can change the x to every id they want to delete.

Comment: @11684 You can get data from AJAX, but since JavaScript runs client-side, you cannot edit the XML.

Comment: The PHP invoked by the AJAX call can do that though. @User7210510310410210511810133

Answer (score 1):

You can't RUN php code in Javascript , but you can INVOKE it through JS/Ajax. For good practice split your php and JS , for example create a page that takes an ID and deletes it's row (i'm guessing your using REST) and invoke it through JS.

Cleaner , effective , and more secure

Answer (score 1):

From your question, i would suggest you give jquery a try.

link to Jquery on your page's head section,

here is your js function

```
function deleteRow(id)
{
 var url='path/to/page.php';
 $("#loading_text").html('Performing Action Please Wait...');
 $.POST(url,{ row_id: id } ,function(data){  $("#loading_text").html(data) }); 
}
```

This should do it for you.

Since its a delete, am using `$.post`  Let me know if you find any more issues

here is a link to jQuery hosted by google CDN
`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js`

This is how your form should look like

```
<form>
<label for="Number"></label>
<input type="text" name="some_name" id="some_id" value="foo bar">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" 
onClick="javascript: deleteRow(the_id_of_the_row);">
</form>
<br>
<div id="loader_text"></div>
```

now your php page that does the delete could look like this

```
<?php
 $row_id = some_sanitisation_function($_POST['row_id']) //so as to clean and check user input
 delete_post($row_id);
 echo "Row deleted Successfully"; //success or failure message
?>
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: @ImriPersiado i expected you to handle the database connection. i dont know how ur tables are setup or how your connection is done...from your question, i saw a php function `delete_post($id)` i believe you had all that covered in the function....all you would do is include the file that has the function or have you not defined your `delete_post($row_id)` function yet?..if that is the case, let me know and i will guide you on how to go about it.

Comment: no problemo...hope your issue is sorted out now..@ImriPersiado